# Burn DVD mastered format DVD+R

Tags: windows-vista, dvd, burning, mastering

Using windows Vista, can I write DVD+R discs using mastered format?

I've followed the instructions [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD)

But when I get to step 6, it gives an error

> "There was an error burning this disc. The disc might no longer be usable"

There are [no dollar signs](http://www.troublefixers.com/error-there-was-an-error-in-burning-this-disc-when-writing-a-disc-in-windows-vista/) in my files or extensions, and I have plenty of free space on my HD.

I can successfully make a data disc using "live" format.  Unfortunately my colleges home (XP) PC is unable to read it, despite the fact that it works on other XP machines at work... so I thought I'd try making a mastered one for greater compatibility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yup you can actually write a mastered data to DVD+R in a vista machine. However there are times where by the disc is not "so" compatible with the drive. You can try changing the brand of the DVD. Sometimes it will work better.